# Service 'iisadmin' (iisadmin) failed to start

Tags: sitecore-commerce

while installing Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 I am getting this error message "Service 'iisadmin' (iisadmin) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services." , any idea what might be causing this? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have checked the Sitecore commerce installation documentation it says you need to install this windows feature `Metabase & IIS 6 compatibility`

[image: Installing windows feature 'Metabase & IIS 6 compatibility']

https://sitecore-commerce-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/installing-commerce-server.html#pre-installation

Comment: Thank you that was the issue it looks that i overlooked that part.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the "IIS metabase and IIS 6 configration compatability" are checked in Windows Features.

Go to it by going to your Windows Control Panel, click on "Programs and Features". On the left side, you should see a link to "Turn Windows features on or off".

Navigate to: Internet Information Services > Web Management Tools > IIS 6 Management Compatibility > IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility (this needs to be checked)